# Using Velocity.js to animate progressbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, velocity.js

I'm trying to switch from using jQuery animation to Velocity as it's supposed to have better performance across devices. From the documentation it seems like it should be fairly easy to do- I've downloaded the source code and added it to my js folder and in my function I should just be able to switch .animate() to .velocity(). Still not working though and I have no console log errors. (Also keep in mind that it worked before with jQuery animate. I've also tried downloading the src code and using the CDNs with no luck)

Here's the code:

```
// PROGRESSBAR
var show_complete_time = 2000; // time to show completed green progressbar and 100% text
function progressbar(progressbar, time) {

    var progressbar = $(progressbar);

    $({someValue: 0}).velocity({someValue: 99}, {
        duration: time,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function() { 
            var widthNumber = this.someValue;
            var number = Math.floor(this.someValue+1);
            progressbar.css({"width": widthNumber + "%"});
            progressbar.html("<p>" + number + '%' + "</p>");
        },
        complete: function(){ // progressbar completed
            progressbar.css({"width": "100%"});
            progressbar.addClass("complete").html("<p>100%</p>");
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the way the jQuery animate function was written wasn't in the correct format for velocity. Velocity takes a map of CSS properties and values as its first argument. An options object can optionally be passed in as a second argument.

Here is the new Velocity function:

```
// PROGRESSBAR
var show_complete_time = 2000; // time to show completed green progressbar and 100% text
function progressbar(progressbar, time) {

    var progressbar = $(progressbar);

    progressbar.velocity({"width": "100%"}, {
        duration: time,
        easing: "linear",
        progress: function(elements, c, r, s, t) { 
            var number = Math.floor((c * 100) + 1);
            progressbar.html("<p>" + number + '%' + "</p>");
        },
        complete: function(){ // progressbar completed
            progressbar.addClass("complete").html("<p>100%</p>");
        }
    });

};
```